# Canvas stops tracking mouse after awhile

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, electron

I've got kind of a strange bug that I'm having trouble figuring out. First, here's the code:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const canvasContainer = document.getElementById('canvas-container');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


function resizeCanvas() {
    canvas.width = canvasContainer.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = canvasContainer.clientHeight;
}



async function init() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas)
    resizeCanvas();



    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);

    let poly = [];

    canvas.addEventListener('click', ev => {
        let x = ev.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        let y = ev.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
        poly.push([x,y]);
    })



    window.addEventListener('keyup', ev => {
        if(ev.key === 'Escape') {
            poly.length = 0;
        }
    });

    let mousePos = null;

    canvas.addEventListener('mouseleave', ev => {
        mousePos = null;
    })

    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', ev => {
        let x = ev.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        let y = ev.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
        mousePos = {x,y};
        console.log(x,y);
    })



    function draw() {
        // ctx.save();

        ctx.fillStyle = '#ADD5F8';

        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        ctx.fillStyle = '#C38F4C';

        if(poly.length >= 3) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(...poly[0]);
            for(let i=1; i<poly.length; ++i) {
                ctx.lineTo(...poly[i]);
            }
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();
        }

        if(poly.length && mousePos) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(...poly[0]);
            for(let i=1; i<poly.length; ++i) {
                ctx.lineTo(...poly[i]);
            }
            if(mousePos) {
                console.log(mousePos);
                ctx.lineTo(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
            }
            ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
            ctx.stroke();
        }


        window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }
}

function createImage(path) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        const img = new Image();
        img.onload = () => resolve(img);
        img.onerror = err => reject(err);
        img.src = path;
    })
}

async function createPattern(path, repetition='repeat') {
    // TODO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21128933/65387
    const img = await createImage(path);
    return ctx.createPattern(img, repetition);
}



init();

// TODO: add physics https://github.com/shakiba/planck.js
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.toolbox {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #535353;
}

.content {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: green;
    flex: 1;
}

.main {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;

}
```

```html
    <div class="main">
      <div class="toolbox">toolbox</div>
      <div id="canvas-container" class="content">
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Interestingly, it seems to work just fine in this fiddle. But when I run it under Electron, [this is what happens](https://i.imgur.com/mZc29uj.gifv) (gifv link) -- (please ignore the fact that the cursor is a little off in the video -- that's jut my screen recorder messing up) -- but do notice that the last red line gets messed up after a few clicks.

The `console.log` in the mousemove handler is firing when I move my mouse, and it's logging the correct coordinates. However, the `mousePos` var that I use inside `draw()` becomes fixated on a certain position and then doesn't update anymore.

I'm updating that same variable on every mouse move event, I don't understand how the two console.logs can come out different?

---

If I log it like this instead, [watch what happens](https://i.imgur.com/XL47C2l.gifv)

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', ev => {
    let x = ev.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    let y = ev.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
    mousePos = {x,y};
    console.log('a',x,y);
})



function draw() {
    if(mousePos) {
        console.log('b', mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
    }
```

"b" gets stuck at {102, 570} even though "a" keeps updating. It's the same variable!

Answer (score 1):

### Odd behaviour, Solution easy

The first thing that struck me looking at your code was the main `init` function was defined as an `async` function, yet contained no awaits.

I am unsure as to the expected behaviour of an `async` function without an `await`, but the problem seems to happen after the same time period.

This is an interesting problem and worth some further investigation. There is a lot to read in the [spec (async function definitions)](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-async-function-definitions) and a quick glance has not shown any obvious reason.

#### Easy fix.

The fix is easy, remove the `async` token from the function `init` and all works fine.

Change

> ```
> async function init() {
> ```

to

```
function init() {
```

#### Example

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const canvasContainer = document.getElementById('canvas-container');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


function resizeCanvas() {
    canvas.width = canvasContainer.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = canvasContainer.clientHeight;
}



function init() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas)
    resizeCanvas();



    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);

    let poly = [];

    canvas.addEventListener('click', ev => {
        let x = ev.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        let y = ev.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
        poly.push([x,y]);
    })



    window.addEventListener('keyup', ev => {
        if(ev.key === 'Escape') {
            poly.length = 0;
        }
    });

    let mousePos = null;

    canvas.addEventListener('mouseleave', ev => {
        mousePos = null;
    })

    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', ev => {
        let x = ev.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        let y = ev.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
        mousePos = {x,y};


    })



    function draw() {
        // ctx.save();

        ctx.fillStyle = '#ADD5F8';

        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        ctx.fillStyle = '#C38F4C';

        if(poly.length >= 3) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(...poly[0]);
            for(let i=1; i<poly.length; ++i) {
                ctx.lineTo(...poly[i]);
            }
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();
        }

        if(poly.length && mousePos) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(...poly[0]);
            for(let i=1; i<poly.length; ++i) {
                ctx.lineTo(...poly[i]);
            }
            if(mousePos) {
     
                ctx.lineTo(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
            }
            ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
            ctx.stroke();
        }


        window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }
}

function createImage(path) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        const img = new Image();
        img.onload = () => resolve(img);
        img.onerror = err => reject(err);
        img.src = path;
    })
}

async function createPattern(path, repetition='repeat') {
    // TODO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21128933/65387
    const img = await createImage(path);
    return ctx.createPattern(img, repetition);
}



init();

// TODO: add physics https://github.com/shakiba/planck.js
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.toolbox {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #535353;
}

.content {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: green;
    flex: 1;
}

.main {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;

}
```

```html
<div class="main">
      <div id="info" class="toolbox">toolbox</div>
      <div id="canvas-container" class="content">
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I removed the `await` for this code example...it was waiting for an image/pattern to load. I'm pretty sure an async function without an await or return just immediately returns `Promise<undefined>`. Or maybe on the next tick, but certainly shouldn't cause this.

Comment: @mpen The `init` resolves on exit (if async) so there is no problem with the function. Having played around with it I discovered that if you don't assign a new object to the mouse  `mousePos = {x,y}` and just assign its properties (eg declared with `const mousePos= {x:0,y:0}` and in event `mousePos.x = x; mousePos.y = y;` using a semaphore to indicate mouse outside canvas) then it works  with `init` as `async`  Its the new mouse object that is getting lost